# Storing help pages on Remote Server

Tags: cocoa

I have made a sample application in which I am able to implement help book via help viewer .

Right now it is storing and displaying content from application bundle, but I want to implement Internet Primary help book content, in which it checks the server to determine whether a newer version of each page is available before displaying the page. If the server isn’t available, or if the page has not been updated, then the local version is used.

I checked this url to implement it: 
http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/ProvidingUserAssitAppleHelp/authoring_help/authoring_help_book.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000903-CH206-CHDGIECE

In it they have specified:

To specify a remote server for your help content, do the following:

1. Click “Show Details.”
2. Click the checkbox labeled “Use remote URL for missing files and updates.”
3. In the text field under this checkbox, enter the server address where your remote help content is available.

Problem is: I cannot get - where to click "Show Details", where to click the checkbox labeled.... is it done within XCode, within help viewer?

Can anyone suggest me exactly how to do it or some useful link to implement it?

Thanks,

Miraaj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You linked to a subsection of a section titled [“Using the Help Indexer Utility”](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/ProvidingUserAssitAppleHelp/authoring_help/authoring_help_book.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000903-CH206-CIHGAIIA). That application is where the Show Details button is.

Answer (score 1):

Read *all* of the section to which you're referring. The parent section is titled "Using the Help Indexer Utility," so it's reasonable to assume those steps are referring to the Help Indexer.app that comes with Xcode Tools.